# How do I make this complex query run faster?

Tags: mysql, subquery

This query is taking between 20-40 seconds to run. I need to speed it up greatly if possible.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.category, a.key 
FROM system_permissions AS a, system_permission_to_role AS b, 
system_user_to_role AS c, system_users AS d 
WHERE 
( 
    ( 
        a.system_permission_id=b.system_permission_id 
        AND (b.system_role_id=c.system_role_id || c.system_role_id = 0) 
        AND a.system_permission_id NOT IN ( 
            SELECT system_permission_id FROM system_permission_exclusions AS f 
            WHERE d.system_user_id=f.system_user_id 
        ) 
        AND c.system_user_id=d.system_user_id 
    ) 
    OR a.system_permission_id IN ( 
        SELECT system_permission_id 
        FROM system_permission_inclusions AS g 
        WHERE d.system_user_id=g.system_user_id 
    ) 
) 
    AND d.ldap_objectguid = '?';
```

The reason behind doing it this way is that I am creating exclusion and inclusion tables for permissions that fall outside of the standard defined roles, so first I need to exclude ones that are part of the role but exist in the exclusion table, then I need to add ones that are NOT part of their role, but exist in the inclusion table.

I am open to the idea of redesigning the tables also.

Comment: You may start by looking at the query execution plan.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, and I am completely blown away that my question would be given a negative rating (huh?) when I thought I expressed the question clearly, posted the code completely, and offered an explanation of the question.

Comment: The question sees reasonable to me. Some people are just dicks.

Comment: You get the execution plan by adding `explain ` infront of your query (`explain SELECT DISTINCT a.category ...`). Also: do you actually get the correct result from that (because your joins, especially in combination with the `or`, look suspicious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.category, P.key 
FROM system_users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN system_permission_inclusions PI ON PI.system_user_id = U.system_user_id
INNER JOIN system_user_to_role UR ON UR.system_user_id = U.system_user_id
INNER JOIN system_permission_to_role PR ON PR.system_role_id = UR.system_role_id
INNER JOIN system_permissions P ON P.system_permission_id = PR.system_permission_id OR P.system_permission_id = PI.system_permission_id
WHERE U.ldap_objectguid = '?'
  AND P.system_permission_id NOT IN (SELECT system_permission_id FROM system_permission_exclusions WHERE system_user_id = U.system_user_id)
```

Comment: Wow! Right out of the gun! 
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.002s

Comment: Thank you so much!